# how to run python code on restricted kernels

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I have a piece of code designed to convert data into embeddings in batches. However, the current issue I'm facing is that when I run this code on a server, it utilizes all 32 available cores. My objective is to make sure that this code only utilizes 16 cores, leaving the remaining 16 cores free. Despite attempting a solution, the code still utilizes all 32 cores.

How to effectively address this problem and ensure that the code operates on only 16 cores?

```
def test_function(a):
    batch_num = 10000
    for i in range(0, len(item_names_clear), batch_num):  
        emb = item_names_clear[i: i + batch_num]
        embeddings = model.encode(emb)
        final = pd.DataFrame({"embeddings":embeddings})
        final.index = item_names_clear[i: i + batch_num]
        start_index = i  
        end_index = i + batch_num - 1 
        filename = f'emb{start_index}_{end_index},.csv'
        final.to_csv(filename) 

num_cores_to_use = 16  

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cores_to_use)
pool.map(test_function, [None] * num_cores_to_use) 
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Tried to use multiprocessing and chatgpt, nothing helped

I don't have GPU